# how to select all data at html table and send it to my database with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I need help ,I want to select all data from html table using javascript and send it to my database with ajax using php i have that code with form that make a html table store data in it ,I want then take data from table to send them to my database

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Order</title>
<script type="text/javascript">


function updateForm() {

var tablename = document.getElementById("tablen").value;
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=tablename;


    var fieldname = document.getElementById("fieldn").value;

    var fieldtype = document.getElementById("fieldt").value;


    var table=document.getElementById("results");
    var row=table.insertRow(-1);

    var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2=row.insertCell(1);


    cell1.innerHTML=fieldname;
    cell2.innerHTML=fieldtype;        


   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="order" method="post" id="frm1">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="tablename">Table Name </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="tablen" name="tablename" title="Please enter only alphabetic characters" type="text" size="28" />
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="fieldname">Field Name</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="fieldn" name="fieldname" title="Enter item quantity" width="196px" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
           <label for="fieldtype">Field Type</label>

        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="fieldtype" id="fieldt" required="required">

            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT">int(11)</option>
            <option value="decimal NOT NULL">decimal</option>
            <option value="varchar(50) NOT NULL">varchar(50)</option>
            <option value="text NOT NULL">text</option>
            <option value="char NOT NULL">char</option>
            <option value="longtext NOT NULL">longtext</option>
            <option value="year NOT NULL">year</option>
            <option value="date NOT NULL">date</option>
            <option value="time NOT NULL">time</option>
            <option value="binary NOT NULL">binary</option>
            <option value="float NOT NULL">float</option>
   </select>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
<input type="reset" name="reset" id="resetbtn" class="resetbtn" value="Reset" />
<button type="button" onClick="updateForm();"/>Add To Table</button>
</form>
<br>



 <form  method="post">

<table id="results" border="2" width="360">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th scope="col" width="120">Table Name</th>
     <th scope="col" width="120">
<p id="demo"></p>
</th>
</tr>
<tr>

    <th scope="col" width="120" id="fieldname1">Field Name</th>
    <th scope="col" width="120" id="fieldtype1">Field Type</th>

</tr>
</thead>
</table>
<button type="button" id="btn"/>Add To DB</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you need to offer more details for an accurate response, what apparently you are asking

> "select all data from html table using javascript"

Would lead me to believe you want to save the actual html to mySQL?

Your problem probably needs specific coding, to your table in question, or, for a more general approach... that depends on your exact needs.

As a general idea, you can go through each of the TR's and do an ajax request for each...

```
$("#yourtableselector tr").each(function() {
var postData = {};
//use $(this).find or similar to get the data you need for each td and add it to the postData variable
$.ajax({ post the data here to a php file of your chosing, that adds the "data" in the database });
});
```